# Fibre Product of $\operatorname{Proj} S$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have problem in doing Hartshorne's exercise II.5.11. It says

> Let $S$ and $T$ be two graded rings with $S_{0}=T_{0}=A .$ We define the Cartesian product $S \times_{A} T$ to be the graded ring $\oplus_{d> 0} S_{d} \otimes_{A} T_{d}$. If $X= \operatorname{Proj} S$ and $Y=\operatorname{Proj} T,$ show that $\operatorname{Proj}(S \times_{A} T) \cong X \times_{A} Y$, and show that the sheaf $\mathscr{O}(1)$ on $\operatorname{Proj}(S \times_{A} T)$ is isomorphic to the sheaf $p_{1}^{*}\left(\mathscr{O}_{X}(1)\right) \otimes p_{2}^{*}\left(\mathscr{O}_{Y}(1)\right)$ on $X \times Y$.

I can show $\operatorname{Proj} (S \times_{A} T) \cong X \times_{A} Y$, by checking in affine neighborhoods. However, I'm stuck in the second statement. My questions are:

**Question 1.** Does $\mathscr{O}(1)$ on $\operatorname{Proj}(S \times_{A} T)$ means $\mathscr{O}_{X\times_A Y}(1)$, when seeing $X\times_A Y$ as $\operatorname{Proj}(S \times_{A} T)$, under the **twisting sheaf of Serre** meaning? (I guess it's right.)

**Question 2.** If $\mathscr{O}(1)$ means the twisting sheaf of Serre, I still have no idea solving it.

Can anyone give me a solution? Thank you very much!

Comment: A formatting tip: \operatorname{Proj} produces the correct formatting for $\operatorname{Proj}$ in math mode. I have upgraded your post with this improvement.

Comment: Vakil 17.2.E is that if $f : Z \rightarrow X$ is any morphism, and $F$ is a quasicoherent sheaf of graded algebras on $X$, then $\underline{\operatorname{Proj}}_Z(f^* F)  = Z \times_X  \underline{\operatorname{Proj}}_X(F) $. Then, 17.3.B states that the composition of two projective morphisms is projective, when the final target is compact. In your situation, $X = Spec(A), Z = Proj(T)$ and $F = S$. Then, $Z \times_X  \underline{\operatorname{Proj}}_X(F) = Proj(T) \times_{A} Proj(S)$ and $\underline{\operatorname{Proj}}_Z(f^* F) \rightarrow X$ is a composition of two projective morphisms.

Comment: @KReiser Thanks for correction.

Comment: @DavidLui Sorry about I can't see the relation with my questions. Could you explain more specifically? Thanks!

Comment: @Jugendtraum It's described in Vakil. The idea is that the fiber product of any morphism with the structure morphism from a Proj is also a Proj.